# Angular 7 - How to limit event trigger to specific component where event occurs?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a list of text areas:

**text-area.component.html**

```html
<!--suppress HtmlFormInputWithoutLabel -->
<textarea [ngClass]="generateTextAreaClass()" (keypress)="onKeyPress($event)">{{ value }}</textarea>
```

The textarea has a `keypress` event.

When I press a key in one of the textareas, it triggers the `keypress` event for all instances of this component.

As a result, I get 5 events being triggered. This obviously doesn't represent the action I just made as a user.

```
{textareaSelector: ".app-utility-textarea-1-1", keypressType: "shift+enter"}
{textareaSelector: ".app-utility-textarea-1-1", keypressType: "shift+enter"}
{textareaSelector: ".app-utility-textarea-1-1", keypressType: "shift+enter"}
{textareaSelector: ".app-utility-textarea-1-1", keypressType: "shift+enter"}
{textareaSelector: ".app-utility-textarea-1-1", keypressType: "shift+enter"}
```

How can I limit the event to only be triggered for the textarea that I'm currently typing in so that only one event gets triggered?

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-utility-textarea',
  templateUrl: './text-area.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./text-area.component.scss']
})
export class TextAreaComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  constructor(private eventBus: EventBusService) {
  }

  @Input() value: string;
  @Input() id: string;
  public textAreaClassPrefix = 'app-utility-textarea';

  ...

  generateTextAreaClass(): string {
    return `${this.textAreaClassPrefix}-${this.id}`;
  }

  onKeyPress(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    if (event.key === 'Enter' && event.shiftKey) {
      event.preventDefault();
      const textAreaKeyPressEvent: TextAreaKeyPressEvent = {
        textareaSelector: this.generateTextAreaClassCSSSelector(),
        keypressType: TextAreaKeyPressType.SHIFT_ENTER
      };
      this.eventBus.textAreaKeyPressSubject$.next(textAreaKeyPressEvent);
    }
  }
}
```

**event-bus.service.ts**

```js
@Injectable()
export class EventBusService {

  public navbarSubject$ = new BehaviorSubject(DashboardNavbarEvent.SIDEBAR_MENU_CLOSED);
  public textAreaKeyPressSubject$ = new Subject<TextAreaKeyPressEvent>();

  constructor() {
  }

}
```

**subscriber.component.ts**

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-subscriber',
  templateUrl: './subscriber.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./subscriber.component.scss']
})
export class SubscriberComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() public block: any;
  @Input() public index: number;

  constructor(private eventBus: EventBusService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.eventBus.textAreaKeyPressSubject$.subscribe((event: TextAreaKeyPressEvent) => {
      console.log(event);
    });
  }

}
```

Comment: How do you know it triggers for all instances? What is `generateTextAreaClass()`?

Comment: added the `generateTextAreaClass()` method. It's just generates a dynamic class identifier that is used for selection later. I have 5 textareas on the page and 5 events being sent to the subject so that was my best assumption.

Comment: Use a getter instead of a method. Angular will take care of that.

Comment: Strange. Can you also add the places where you subscribe to `textAreaKeyPressSubject$`?

Comment: Based on the output it seems all 5 calls are coming from the same component (the one with id 1-1.

Comment: yeap. Just realized that. I just added a log to the `onKeyPress` method and it's only entering the `event.key === 'Enter' && event.shiftKey` condition once. I wonder if there's an issue with the subscription. Just updated the question with event bus and subscriber.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this was a design problem. I was subscribing to the `textAreaKeyPressSubject$` inside another component that had 5 instances. Every instance ended up subscribing to the `textAreaKeyPressSubject$` on init and logged the event 1 time each.

The `keypress` event was only triggered once in the `textarea.component.ts` where I was typing.

When I moved the subscription to this subject to a parent component that only had one instance, this issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

you are using a subject from [subject](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/subject):

> What is a Subject? An RxJS Subject is a special type of Observable that allows values to be multicasted to many Observers. While plain Observables are unicast (each subscribed Observer owns an independent execution of the Observable), Subjects are multicast.

And you are emitting an event by next in :

```
this.eventBus.textAreaKeyPressSubject$.next(textAreaKeyPressEvent);
```

so basically you are emitting something to multicast subscribers, so the event is fired from the right one textarea as you can see but you're propagating the event to the other subscribers. The point is that you want one to one subscription and not one to many. Hope this was helpful